# Where are the integration test reports for Grails?

Tags: testing, grails, report, integration-testing

When I execute:

```
grails test-app
```

It executes both the unit and integration tests.

The output also says that I should check my test-reports directory for the results

```
| Tests PASSED - view reports in ~/../target/test-reports
```

When I look in there, it only has reports for my unit tests, not integration.

Is this a bug?

Answer (score 1):

You would see that the test report says Unit Test Results but you would find your integration tests as well in the list. If you select "Package Summary" you would be able to see the difference properly.

[Grails 2.2.0]
I am also assuming that command `grails create-integration-test` is used for creating integration tests.

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem was, but it started working.  I had manually created the tests and put them in the right place, but after I ran create-integration-test once, the reports began to generate.

Comment: @SohelKatchi Glad I was able to help in some other way. :)

Comment: For Grails 3.2.8, you can see the report at `build/reports/tests/index.html`

Answer (score 0):

Concerning Grails 3.2.13, the test results are saved in `build/test-results`.

Integration test results go to `build/test-results/integrationTest` directory. Unit test results go to `build/test-results/test` directory.